# Three curly brackets together in php source code

Tags: php, vim, folding, curly-braces

I just downloaded  complete source code of PHP from php.net (PHP 5.4.0 [tar.bz2]).
They are often using three curly brackets together as given below (The following code snippet extracted form ext/ctype/ctype.c.)

```
/* {{{ proto bool ctype_digit(mixed c)
   Checks for numeric character(s) */
 static PHP_FUNCTION(ctype_digit)
 {
  CTYPE(isdigit);
 }
/* }}} */
```

Does anyone have the idea why they are using these three curly brackets together?

Comment: They're used by some editors to "fold" blocks of code so only the text in the comment line itself is visible, and the actual code is "folded" away.

Comment: I don't think just for the sake of folding they are allowing to add three curly brackets.

Comment: @HabeebPerwad It's in comment blocks - they can "allow" whatever they want in there. :)

Comment: See also: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/CODING_STANDARDS#L215

Answer (score 33, accepted):

They are [vim fold markers](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/CODING_STANDARDS.md#documentation-and-folding-hooks), they make it easy to collapse and expand the text inbetween the triple curly braces in vim, in the example shown alternating between:

```
...

/* {{{ proto bool ctype_digit(mixed c)
   Checks for numeric character(s) */
static PHP_FUNCTION(ctype_digit)
{
    CTYPE(isdigit);
}
/* }}} */

...
```

and just

```
...

/* {{{ proto bool ctype_digit(mixed c)

...
```

If you look at the [end of the file where you find them](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/ctype/ctype.c?view=markup#l271), you'll often find a block like this:

```
/*
 * Local variables:
 * tab-width: 4
 * c-basic-offset: 4
 * End:
 * vim600: sw=4 ts=4 fdm=marker
 * vim<600: sw=4 ts=4
 */
```

Which is another more-obvious indicator that these comments relate to vim.

Comment: And I am a big fan of folding Now!

Comment: I just couldn't live without folding in vim!
zf, c, zd, zi and zi are now lying deep inside my muscle-memory, since 2011.